# Can the eye determine which type of defocus is presented to it?

Tags: human-anatomy, brain, biophysics, eyes, human-eye

I have a question regarding myopic and hyperopic defocus.

My question is, is the eye able to determine which type of defocus is presented to it and if so what mechanisms allow it to distinguish between the two types of defocus. This question was thought of after reading a study which showed that the eye's AL could change temporality based on which type of defocus was presented to it and I was unable to find a definitive answer on to why this happens.

As well as this, I saw numerous reports on how different lenses can slow the progression of myopia by presenting peripheral myopic defocus onto the retina without an explanation on why this occurs.

Thank you for taking the time to read my question and I look forward to your response!